# I cannot figure out why I cannot access localhost:5000 when localhost:3000 works just fine for a simple API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I'm attempting to run a simple API in node. I've attached the github repo here: https://github.com/zsmith-dfw/api-example

When I run the program in the command prompt, it states that it is listening on port 5000. When I go to http://localhost:5000, I'm presented with a "this site cannot be reached" error. When I attempt to make the GET request in Postman, I get Error: read ECONNRESET. If I try this with port 3000 however, I get the returned JSON as expected in both http://localhost:3000 as well as the GET request in Postman. I had this program running fine on a previous computer but am absolutely baffled why it doesn't work now. The code is good - it must be some kind of issue with my PC (Windows 10). Here is what I have tried so far:

1. Uninstalled and reinstalled Node
2. globally installed http-server
3. disabled Firewall settings
4. verified nothing was running on port 500 with the npx kill-port 5000 command

Completely out of ideas at this point. Will provide any other requested info. Thanks so much

Comment: Even this app.listen(5000,'0.0.0.0') does not work?

Comment: No I don't think so, unless I'm defining the port variable wrong. Sorry, I'm still learning. Other student's have ran this code "as is" and did not get the issue with localhost:5000 that I am facing, which is why it must be some sort of problem with a setting on my PC rather than the code itself.

Comment: it works on every other port except for 5000?

Comment: @Zac Well it works on 3000 like I said and I just tried 80. But I don't understand why it won't work on 5000.

Comment: `app.listen(5000).on('error', function(err) { console.error(err) });` log error if port is already in used.

Comment: What is the risen error?Are you sure that there is not other service use the 5000 port in your computer?

Comment: There is nothing else running on port 5000....I already said that I ran the kill command. And I even inserted the error handler to see if the port was in use and no change.